# How to programmatically access <INTERCEPT-URL> from <HTTP> element in spring security

Tags: java, security, spring, spring-security, spring-3

How can I programmatically access the contents of the intercept-url declarations (from the http://www.springframework.org/schema/security schema)? E.g.,

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" filters="none" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    ...
</http>
```

Spring security role mapping is used to restrict access to certain pages. I want to extract the same role mapping information (the *pattern* and *accept* attributes) to be able to only show those pages in the html-menu that each role has access to see.

I've had a look at the `HttpConfigurationBuilder`, but it's package protected and doesn't seem to offer so much information. I've also tried:

```
  FilterSecurityInterceptor interceptor = appContext.getBean(FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
  if (interceptor != null) {
      for (ConfigAttribute attr : interceptor.getSecurityMetadataSource().getAllConfigAttributes()) {
          // Extract the attributes ... 
          attr.getAttribute();
      }
  }
```

but I only managed to access the roles, not the url patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration declared using a namespace support does not exists in the same "format" after application context is loaded.

If you want to preserve the role mapping information, you need to access it while configuration parsing - and save the data you need for the future use. You can do this by subclassing `org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser`, reading the data you want and delegating to `super`.

See [Spring Security 3 - Appendix D. Extensible XML authoring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html) for usage of custom `BeanDefinitionParser` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can check if `getFilterChainMap`() method of `FilterChainProxy` class gives you the relevant info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortuntely it doesn't provide me with the necessary information. The map key matches the url pattern, put the map value is the chain of filters (BasicAuthenticationFilter, securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,......, FilterSecurityInterceptor). It almost seems that I must parse the xml context manually to achieve what I want.